# How to revert back to mixed case word after using .lower()?

Tags: python

The `.lower()` function was needed to convert 'word' to all lower case as the code was needed to not be case-sensitive. However, now I need it to revert back to its mixed case original word for me to perform a function which counts the upper and lower case characters (which I have already done).

Comment: You can't, because you don't know any more which weren't uppercase to start with.

Comment: You need two names, one with the original string, and the other with the `.lower()` string.

Comment: just assign the original to a different variable

Answer (score 2):

You must keep track of the old word to be able to restore it:

```
word = 'MixedCase'
old_word = word             # old_word -> 'MixedCase'
word = word.lower()         # word -> 'mixedcase'

# restore:
word = old_word             # word -> 'MixedCase'
```